# EC2-Describe-Instances for DNS

Tags: linux, bash, perl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I found a script online a few months ago that I changed and came up with the solution below.
It uses EC2-Describe-Instances and uses Perl to collect the Instance Names, IP address and updates Route53.

It works but its a bit in-efficient, I'm more of a .Net programmer and I am a little out of my depth so hopefully someone can help or point me in the right direction.

What I am thinking is I want it to save a copy of EC2-Describe-Instances from last time it ran and then get a fresh copy. Compare the differences and then only run the Route53 update for Instances that have changed IP. Any Ideas?

```
    #!/bin/bash

set root='dirname $0'
ec2-describe-instances -O ###### -W ##### --region eu-west-1 |
perl -ne '/^INSTANCE\s+(i-\S+).*?(\S+\.amazonaws\.com)/ 
and do { $dns = $2; print "$1 $dns\n" }; /^TAG.+\sName\s+(\S+)/
and print "$1 $dns\n"' | 
perl -ane 'print "$F[0] CNAME $F[1] --replace\n"' |
grep -v '^i-' |
xargs --verbose -n 4 -I myvar /bin/sh -c '{ /usr/local/bin/cli53 rrcreate -x 300 contoso.com 'myvar'; sleep 1; printf "\n\n"; }'
```

--edit--

Basically what I need is a way to compare a saved file with the output of EC2-Describe-Instances and then only return lines that contain differences to be fed back into the rest of the code.

Something like:

ChangedLines(File.txt, "ec2-describe-instances -O ###### -W ##### --region eu-west-1") | perl......

If 
File 1 =
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL

Output =
ABC
DEF
GHJ
JKL

Return =
GHJ

**Example of EC2-Descibe-Instances**

```
PROMPT> ec2-describe-instances

RESERVATION r-1a2b3c4d  111122223333    my-security-group
INSTANCE    i-1a2b3c4d  ami-1a2b3c4d    ec2-203-0-113-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com    ip-10-251-50-12.ec2.internal    running my-key-pair 0       t1.micro    YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+0000    us-west-2a  aki-1a2b3c4d            monitoring-disabled 184.73.10.99    10.254.170.223          ebs                 paravirtual xen ABCDE1234567890123  sg-1a2b3c4d default false   
BLOCKDEVICE     /dev/sda1       vol-1a2b3c4d    YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ    true    
RESERVATION     r-2a2b3c4d      111122223333    another-security-group
INSTANCE    i-2a2b3c4d  ami-2a2b3c4d    ec2-203-0-113-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com    ip-10-251-50-12.ec2.internal    running my-key-pair 0       t1.micro    YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+0000    us-west-2c          windows monitoring-disabled 50.112.203.9    10.244.168.218          ebs                 hvm xen ABCDE1234567890123  sg-2a2b3c4d default false
BLOCKDEVICE     /dev/sda1        vol-2a2b3c4d    YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ   true
```

I need to capture the lines in which the IP address has changed from the previous run.

Comment: All the Perl three-liner does is grep some data from the output and present it in a nice way. What you need here is bash-knowledge, not Perl. I'll change the tags for you.

Comment: Also what you need to do is add a new call to `ec2-describe-instances` with the same args to the top, write that to file and then add a `diff` of that file and the same call *above* it. Take the output and if there is no change, abort the script.

Comment: @simbabque Thanks, I can guarantee there will be changes every time it runs however there are about a hundred iterations and only about a dozen actual changes that need to be done so I need to get just the records that have changed.

Comment: Maybe you can outline your algorithm as pseudo-code in the question, then someone can help you bash-script or perl-script it. But we will not just write it for you.

Comment: Ye thats fair enough. 
I can do most of it myself. What I am struggling to find and what I need help with is a way to compare a Saved copy of EC2-Describe-Instances with a newly run version and only return the lines which are different.
E.g
'code' ChangedLines(fileone.txt, "ec2-describe-instances -O ###### -W ##### --region eu-west-1") | perl..........

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add that.

Comment: It sounds like you need the [Data::Difference](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Difference) module

Comment: Could you show a sample of the output from the `ec2-describe-instances` command and describe the output you would like?

Comment: Example attached.
If in the INSTANCE line the IP is different to the last time, I need to return the line. But if its the same as last time then ignore it. Bit like how grep returns lines only showing changes not a static string.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your actual goal is to update Amazon Route 53 for newly launch Amazon EC2 instances. There's a few different approaches you could take.

### List instances launched during a given period

Use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to list instances that were recently launched. I found this example on https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1209:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[?LaunchTime>=`2015-03-01`][].{id: InstanceId, type: InstanceType, launched: LaunchTime}'
```

Modified for your needs:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[?LaunchTime>=`2015-03-01`][].{id: InstanceId, ip: PrivateIpAddress}' --output text
```

### Let the instance update itself

Thinking a different way, why not have the instances update Amazon Route 53 themselves? Use a start script (via User Data) that calls the AWS CLI to update Route 53 directly!

Instances can retrieve their IP address via [instance metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval):

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4/public/
```

Then call `aws route53 change-resource-record-sets` to update records.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a play with this and see how I get on. Ye I tried getting the instances to update themselves but were not finding it very reliable so we are running the script about as a double check however it takes 15 mins + to run as it updates everything and not just incorrect records.

Comment: Any logging to explain the "not reliable" bit? You could have new instances push their existence into a queue and have something else process from the queue.